# How to add reference to SharedProject in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, prism

I develop Prism 6 WPF modular application and I use there a SharedProject called 'CommonResources' - please see below:

[image]

This SharedProject has two folders: 'Classes' and 'Styles'. There is 'RadiobuttonStyle.xaml' file with common ResourceDictionary in 'Styles' folder (for styling of RadioButtons in my application). Below I partially display the ResourceDictionary:

```
<ResourceDictionary    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CommonResources.Styles"
                xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
                xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
                mc:Ignorable="d" 
                xmlns:ed="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/drawing">

<!--Style for radiobuttons, used for view-switching-->
<Style x:Key="MainViewRadioButtonStyle" TargetType="RadioButton">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF483D8B"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF6A5ACD" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
                <Grid>
                . . . . . . . . . . .
```

I added reference to 'CommonResources' SharedProject both in 'Authorization' module and 'Calibration' module. In XAML of RadioButtons in modules (for example 'AuthorizationNavigationItemView' RadioButton in AuthorizationModule swittching to 'Authorization' view) I write:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Authorization.Views.AuthorizationNavigationItemView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
         xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
         prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/CommonResources;component/Styles/RadiobuttonStyle.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
```

But in string

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/CommonResources;component/Styles/RadiobuttonStyle.xaml"/>
```

there is an error reporting that: *There are no references to CommonResources assembly in this project*. And the same is in XAML of the other RadioButton. How can I add reference to 'CommonResources' ShareProject in XAML of each RadioButton?

Comment: What is the assemblyname of CommonResources.csproj. Go to project properties and check Assembly name in Application tab

Comment: For SharedProject project its properties is not displayed when I right-click it in the solution and choose Properties.

Comment: you should see something like this: https://www.google.sk/search?q=assemblyname+project+properties&safe=off&biw=2021&bih=1037&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwif493PwI3LAhVIGCwKHZTKAi4Q_AUICCgD&dpr=0.95#safe=off&tbm=isch&q=assembly+name+project+properties+visual+studio+2015&imgrc=b5DRShTyoS8KBM%3A

Comment: you have to click on project properties, not solution properties: https://www.google.sk/search?q=assemblyname+project+properties&safe=off&biw=2021&bih=1037&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwif493PwI3LAhVIGCwKHZTKAi4Q_AUICCgD&dpr=0.95#safe=off&tbm=isch&q=assembly+name+project+properties+visual+studio+2015&imgrc=9biHfQ9S91mLzM%3A

Comment: I right-clicked exactly on SharedProject in my solution but not on the solution itself and the tab with its properties wasn't displayed.

Comment: Well I can't help you with Visual Studio in Cyrillic. Post screenshot